# C++ Only reading last line when reading text from a list

Tags: c++, file

Ive written a loop function that compares a type String to another String, like such

```
double robotComplexity() { 
  double complexity;
  if(newChar == "A") {
    cout << "Character: " << newChar;
  } else {
    cout << "Program isnt working! :(";
  }

  if(complexity > 100) {
    complexity = 100;
  }

  cout << "\nThe Robot Complexity is: " << complexity << endl;
  return complexity;
}
```

However when the program runs, the latter of the if statement returns "Program does not work :("

However within the text file there is in fact a record that contains a  character of A

```
A:Head:1:2:15.
B:Torso:0:6:5.
C:Leg:0:4:6.
D:Arm:0:4:8.
E:Tail:0:6:2.
```

I am unsure is why the loop function doesnt recongize it. The expected output for would return "A" in string form, as the program loops for the records of the file until it locates the character A linked to a variable partCode. As of now it does not do this.

My full program is as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "driver.h"
#include <sstream> 
#include <fstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


//declaration of customer varialbes
std::string customerName;
std::string projectName;
std::string partNumber;;

//declaration of parts variables
char partCode;
std::string partName;
int maximum;
int minimum;
int complexity;

//declaration of builder variables
std::string name;
int ability;
int variability;

std::vector<string> builderVector;
std::vector<string> partsVector;
std::vector<string> customerVector;

std::ifstream buildersList("Builders.txt");
std::ifstream partsList("Parts.txt");
std::ifstream customerList("Customers.txt");
std::string outputFile = "output.txt";
std::string input;

std::string newChar;
std::stringstream convertChar;



void readFile() //function to read Builders, Customers and Parts text file
{
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(partsList, line)) {
      line.pop_back();         //removing '.' at end of line
      std::string token;
      std::istringstream ss(line);

      convertChar << partCode;
      convertChar >> newChar;


      // then read each element by delimiter
      int counter = 0;//number of elements you read
      while (std::getline(ss, token, ':')) {  //spilt into different records
        switch (counter) {//put into appropriate value-field according to element-count

        case 0: newChar = token; //convert partCode from a char to a string 
          break;
        case 1: partName   = token;       break;
        case 2: maximum    = stoi(token); break;
        case 3: minimum    = stoi(token); break;
        case 4: complexity = stoi(token); break;
        default:                          break;
        }
        counter++;  //increasing counter
      }
      //cout << "Part Code: " << newChar << endl;
      // cout << "Part Name: "<< partName << endl;
      // cout << "Maximum: "<< maximum << endl;
      // cout << "Minimum: "<< minimum << endl;
      // cout << "Complexity: "<< complexity << endl;
    }

    while (std::getline(customerList, line)) {
      line.pop_back();//removing '.' at end of line
      std::string token;
      std::istringstream ss(line);

      // then read each element by delimiter
      int counter = 0;//number of elements you read
      while (std::getline(ss, token, ':')) {//spilt into different records
        switch (counter) {//put into appropriate value-field according to element-count
        case 0: customerName = token; break;
        case 1: projectName  = token; break;
        case 2: partNumber   = token; break;
        default:                      break;
        }
        counter++;//increasing counter
      }
      // cout << "Customers name: " << customerName << endl;
      // cout << "Project name: "<< projectName << endl;
      // cout << "Part number: "<< partNumber << endl;
    }
}


double robotComplexity() { 

  double complexity;
  while(partsList.is_open) {
    if(newChar == "A") {
     cout << "Character: " << newChar;
    } else {
     cout << "Program isnt working! :(";
    }
  }

  if(complexity > 100) {
     complexity = 100;
  }

  cout << "\nThe Robot Complexity is: " << complexity << endl;
  return complexity;
}


double robotVariability() {
  double variability;
  cout << "\nThe Robot Variability is: " << variability << endl;
  return variability;
}

void writeFile() //writes to a file output.txt the end calculations. 
{

}
```

Main file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "driver.h"
#include "implementation.cpp"
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int main() {
  readFile();
  writeFile();
  robotComplexity();
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

If anyone can provide a solution that would be great.

Comment: @bobah yes. why?

Comment: @DavidLing Your code isn't indented

Comment: @Kerek it is for me

Comment: I'd first get rid of global variables. Normally it would be these, to cloud the author from spotting the problem (because you cannot trace what came from where and in which order).

Comment: @DavidLing Something in the process of pasting the code into here made it lose its indentation. Anyhow, I cannot see where you actually put the value inside of `newChar`. And the code isn't organized well. You should try not to use so many global variables, it is a bad habit (and probably what is masking your error)

Comment: @Kerek Okay i will remember for next time. Inregards to newChar, it is declared in the first while loop of my readFile function

Comment: @DavidLing I suggest you rewrite the code, probably, if you write it properly, it will work, if it doesn't, then ask again

Comment: @Kerek no the code is fine. I asked my professor he just told me that when the loop occurs, its only going to read the last line and i need to fix it so that doenst happen. So rewritting wont help at all in this case.

Comment: @Kerek thus the nature of my questions name...

Answer (score 0):

I have just rearranged your code, as it should look like, and it works properly.

In coding, having a messy code means having bugs you can not trace. Split your code to the smallest logical components, and write the code so it will be readable (***no need for comments in code!***). I have done nothing fancy other than reorganizing the parsing code.

Also, notice that you have a dot (`.`) in the end of each line, you should either remove it from the input, or handle it in code.

```
// these are the streams used:
#include <istream>
#include <sstream>

std::vector<std::string> parse_stream(std::istream& stream)
{
    std::vector<std::string> res{};

    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(stream, line))
    {
        res.push_back(line);
    }

    return res;
}

std::vector<std::string> split_line(std::istream& stream, char delimiter)
{
    std::vector<std::string> res{};

    std::string token;
    while(std::getline(stream, token, delimiter))
    {
        res.push_back(token);
    }

    return res;
}

void print_vector(const std::vector<std::string>& vec)
{
    for (const std::string& str: vec)
    {
        std::cout << str << ", ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::string in_str = "A:Head:1:2:15\nB:Torso:0:6:5\nC:Leg:0:4:6\nD:Arm:0:4:8\nE:Tail:0:6:2";
    std::istringstream ss{in_str};

    auto parsed_stream = parse_stream(ss);
    print_vector(parsed_stream);

    for (const auto& line : parsed_stream)
    {
        std::istringstream line_ss{line};

        auto splited_line = split_line(line_ss, ':');
        print_vector(splited_line);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
A:Head:1:2:15, B:Torso:0:6:5, C:Leg:0:4:6, D:Arm:0:4:8, E:Tail:0:6:2, 

A, Head, 1, 2, 15, 

B, Torso, 0, 6, 5, 

C, Leg, 0, 4, 6, 

D, Arm, 0, 4, 8, 

E, Tail, 0, 6, 2,
```

Comment: why this? std::string in_str = "A:Head:1:2:15\nB:Torso:0:6:5\nC:Leg:0:4:6\nD:Arm:0:4:8\nE:Tail:0:6:2"; this is not my original at all

Comment: @DavidLing since I'm doing it online, I cannot access files. However, I'm using `std::istringstream` which behaves like `std::ifstream` in that they both are `std::istream`. Just translated your file into a string.

Comment: @DavidLing Also, notice that my function should handle both a file and a stringstream the same (by using their common interface instead of the specific type)